# Label not affected by AnchorLayout - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have just started learning kivy and am stuck with this layout problem.
I used the Anchor Layout to center a button using:

`Button:
    text: "A button"
    anchor_x:'center'
    anchor_y:'center'`

However when I try this:

```
Label:
    text: "Hello World!"
    size_hint: 1, 1
    anchor_x:'center'
    anchor_y:'top'
```

It just shows "Hello World!" in the default center position but I want it above my centered button.

I have tried everything and looked at the docs but have found nothing to explain this.

Edit:
Here are both files:

py file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class Layout(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class LayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LayoutApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<Layout>:
    Label:
        text: "Hello World!"
        font_size: 50
        size_hint: None, None
        height: 100
        anchor_x:'center'
        anchor_y:'top'

    Button:
        text: "Button"
        background_colour: (0,0,1,1)
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 50, 50
        anchor_x:'center'
        anchor_y:'top'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> size_hint: 1, 1

This is your problem, the size_hint means the Label is the same size as the parent layout, with the text in the middle...i.e. the middle of the screen. It doesn't matter where the label is anchored, because there's no room for it to move.

You should instead manually set the size you want, e.g.

```
size_hint_y:  None
height: 50
```

Comment: I tried this but the label still stays in the center.

Comment: I also just commented the anchor lines of the button and it stays in the center.

Comment: Ah, I missed the other problem - anchor_x and anchor_y are properties of the layout, not the children. It will anchor all its children to the same place. You probably want to use a FloatLayout instead.