# Why none of Kivy's layouts work as expected?

Tags: python, kivy

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish, should be simple: **A header text in a Label with some vertical buttons listed under it and nested a bit to the right**

First trial:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0


<SubjectButton@Button>:

  size_hint: None, None
  size: 40, 160

BoxLayout:

  orientation: "vertical"

  Label:
    text: "Choose Subject:"
    font_size: "16sp"
    bold: True
    halign: "left"


  BoxLayout:

    orientation: "vertical"
    padding_horizontal: 20

    SubjectButton:
       text: "Subject 1"

    SubjectButton:
      text: "Subject 2"

    SubjectButton:
      text: "Subject 3"

    SubjectButton:
      text: "Subject 4"
```

Result:
[image: what's that supposed to mean?]

Second Trial:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

#: set sb_width 120
#: set sb_height 40
#: set sb_margin_left 20

<SubjectButton@Button>:

size_hint: None, None
height: sb_height
width: sb_width


RelativeLayout:

Label:
    text: "Choose Subject:"
    font_size: "16sp"
    bold: True
    halign: "left"
    pos: 0, root.height - 5

SubjectButton:
    text: "Subject 1"
    pos: sb_margin_left, root.height - sb_height

SubjectButton:
    text: "Subject 2"
    pos: sb_margin_left, root.height - 2 * sb_height

SubjectButton:
    text: "Subject 3"
    pos: sb_margin_left, root.height - 3 * sb_height

SubjectButton:
    text: "Subject 4"
    pos: sb_margin_left, root.height - 4 * sb_height
```

Result:

[image: Where's my label]

Label is gone!.

Let me first say that the idea that layouts start at top-left and explicit positioning at bottom-left is stupid (coming from PySide). How is that supposed to work?.

That's not to mention that [AnchorLayout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html) is not actually a layout but an alignment tool. It doesn't affect but a single child.

What am I missing here?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First trial:

Your problem here is that you set your button heights manually and made them 1/4 of the Window height. What you're seeing is them overflowing the BoxLayout height because of this, apparently doing so from the top. You generally don't want to set manual heights so directly, but let the BoxLayout set the size so that it adjusts nicely to changes in the window size.

I'm not sure exactly what you're actually going for, but here is an example using nested boxlayouts to fix the obvious problems:

```
<SubjectButton@Button>:                                                                                                                            
    # size rules deleted                                                                                                                           

BoxLayout:                                                                                                                                         

    orientation: "vertical"                                                                                                                        

    Label:                                                                                                                                         
        text: "Choose Subject:"                                                                                                                    
        font_size: "16sp"                                                                                                                          
        bold: True                                                                                                                                 
        halign: "left"                                                                                                                             
        valign: 'middle'                                                                                                                           
        text_size: self.size                                                                                                                       


    BoxLayout:                                                                                                                                     
        Widget:                                                                                                                                    
            size_hint_x: None                                                                                                                      
            width: 10                                                                                                                              
        BoxLayout:                                                                                                                                 

            orientation: "vertical"                                                                                                                
            padding_horizontal: 20                                                                                                                 

            SubjectButton:                                                                                                                         
                text: "Subject 1"                                                                                                                  

            SubjectButton:                                                                                                                         
                text: "Subject 2"                                                                                                                  

            SubjectButton:                                                                                                                         
                text: "Subject 3"                                                                                                                  

            SubjectButton:                                                                                                                         
                text: "Subject 4"                                                                                                                  
        Label:                                                                                                                                     
            text: 'free space'
```

Note that I also set `text_size: self.size` in the Label so that your alignment takes effect. I also added vertical alignment.

I included the spacing with a Widget spacer. Probably a padding argument could do the same thing but I didn't check the api for it.

> Second Trial:
>   Label is gone!.

It's not gone, you just set its y position to 5 pixels below the top of the screen, so you can't see the text. You can see where it really is by adding e.g. the following to its kv rule, which is useful to see where apparently-missing widgets are:

```
    canvas: 
        Color: 
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1 
        Rectangle: 
            pos: self.pos 
            size: self.size
```

Using a RelativeLayout for this is a bad idea anyway, it's nicer to use nested layouts as above.

> Let me first say that the idea that layouts start at top-left and explicit positioning at bottom-left is stupid (coming from PySide). How is that supposed to work?.

I suppose it's inconsistent in a sense, but honestly I've never even noticed it as an issue. Is it causing you a particular problem?

> That's not to mention that AnchorLayout is not actually a layout but an alignment tool. It doesn't affect but a single child.

Not sure what you mean here...the AnchorLayout lays out its children just as any other layout does.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the idea of empty spacer widgets. I ended up with a variant of the first solution for now. `AnchorLayout` is an alignment tool for a single widget as per my experience and your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337720/label-not-affected-by-anchorlayout-kivy#comment39520611_25339313.